# Why do I get an Error 400 on my GraphQl mutation?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to set up GraphQl in a React / Express (Apollo) project. I built the authentication (which works well), but I'd like to add the possibility for users to delete their account. With my code, I get this error:

```js
POST http://localhost:5005/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

Where did I go wrong?

This is my code:

Resolvers (server) function:

```
const resolvers = {
    ...rest

    Mutation: {
        ...rest
        deleteUser: async (_, { id }) => {
            if (!id) {
                throw new ApolloError("ID is missing", "ID_MISSING")
            }
            
            await User.findByIdAndDelete(id)
            
            return `User ${id} was deleted successfully`
        },
    },
}
```

typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    ...rest
    type Mutation {
        ...rest
        deleteUser(id: ID): String
    }
`
```

Front end:

```
const DELETE_USER = gql`
    mutation deleteUser($id: ID!) {
        deleteUser(id: $id)
    }
`

const DeleteAccount = () => {
    const [deleteUser, { loading: deleteLoading }] = useMutation(DELETE_USER)

    const handleDelete = () => {
        deleteUser({
            variables: {
                id: user?._id,
            },

            onError: ({ graphQLErrors }) => {
                console.log(graphQLErrors[0])
            },
        }).then(() => {
            logoutUser()
            navigate("/login")
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            ...rest
            <button onClick={deleteUser}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If I run this command on Apollo studio it works:

```
mutation {
  deleteUser(id: "6346dfdc83dd01ef17a8ee8f")
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Edit:

I tried clicking on the button again, this time it worked. But then I tried to create a new account and delete this one again, but this time got this error again

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
mutation deleteUser($id: ID!)
```

Which means the `$id` variable is required. But then you have:

```
const handleDelete = () => {
  deleteUser({
    variables: {
      id: user?._id,
    },
…
```

If `user` is not defined then you'll be passing undefined as the id and you'll get the 400 error because the request is invalid. Suggest:

```
const handleDelete = () => {
  if(user?._id) deleteUser({
    variables: {
      id: user._id,
    },
…
```

Furthermore you should **never** pass the current user's ID as a variable from the client as then in this case you are potentially allowing any (malicious) user to delete any other user. Get the current user's ID from the GraphQL *context* instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. At the moment I'm using React useContext and JWT to get the user (and their ID), but if it's not secure enough (from what I understand from your answer) I'll investigate this GraphQL context instead

Comment: Your GraphQL context function should be decoding the JWT and extracting the user object from there. If you then add the user object as a key on `req` then it will be available to all your resolvers and mutations.